# Tips on introducing my paper on Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

For a homework assignment I'm beginning to write a relatively short (4-pages) paper on Dedekind cuts and I'm struggling to introduce the subject. I have previously given a presentation on the subject where I just said: Dedekind are a construction of real numbers which is interesting, and i begun.. However for my paper I have to write a good introduction paragraph and I can't seem to find a good way to introduce the subject. I hope someone might have a good tip

Comment: One way is to try to state in non-technical terms what problem Dedekind was solving by introducing his cuts: to give a tiny bit of background on the history of the foundations of real analysis or whatever, showing where cuts came from.

Comment: A quote from Dedekind might be a good hook to hang your introduction on. Maybe you could read one of his papers or *Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen* (there are translations if you don't read German)

Comment: Following Matthew Towers's comment: [Essays on the Theory of Numbers by Richard Dedekind - Free Ebook](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21016)